# How can I automatically insert values into a new column I made based on a column that already exists in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I had an `employee` table that stored some data which includes `salary`.
I added another column `grade`.

```
If salary is between 0-2000 grade is 1.
If between 2000-3000 grade is 2.
If more than 3000 than 3.
```

Do I need to manually do this through `UPDATE` or is it possible to define this condition with `ALTER`.

Comment: If you are using latest version of MySQL; you can look at Generated Columns. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this with an update.  But, you might find it better to use a generated column:

```
alter table employee add grade int generated as
    (case when salary < 2000 then 1 when salary < 3000 then 2 else 3 end);
```

This is handy, because you don't have to update the grade if the score changes or when new rows are added.  `GRADE` is calculated when it is used.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the best option is to use [CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) as @Madhur mentioned in the comment

And another option is to use update query below, but take into account that any salary value update may brake the relation between `salary` and `grade` columns.

```
UPDATE `employee ` SET `grade` = CASE
    WHEN salary >= 0 AND salary <=2000 THEN 1
    WHEN salary > 2000 AND salary <=3000 THEN 2
    WHEN salary > 3000 THEN 3
    ELSE `0`
    END
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to store the grade in the table? You can always extract the grade from the salary.
In your select you can use the case statement.

Comment: `case` **expression** !